# Can Non-German Nationals with Niederlassungserlaubnis Apply for a German ID Card (Personalausweis)

Tags: resident-permit

My Niederlassungserlaubnis was issued last year. Still, whenever I travel within the EU, I am required to carry my passport as the Niederlassungserlaubnis only serves as a residency permit and not a German ID card, as I learned from a document check conducted by a gate agent at Ryanair during a flight from Berlin to Mallorca.

Although the Niederlassungserlaubnis certifies my right to reside and work in Germany indefinitely, it is not intended primarily for identification purposes. I recently discovered that it might be possible to apply for a Personalausweis while holding a Niederlassungserlaubnis, the German Identity Card Act does not explicitly state whether non-German nationals with a Niederlassungserlaubnis are eligible. https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_pauswg/englisch_pauswg.html and https://www.personalausweisportal.de/.

I am curious whether this is possible and would appreciate any official links mentioning "Niederlassungserlaubnis" and non-German nationals.

If no one has any information, I have scheduled an appointment with the Burgeramt for this. Let's see if they apply personalausweis for me.

Comment: No, it is only for German citizens, that can be inferred from https://southafrica.diplo.de/sa-en/sa-consular/sa-id/2192778

Comment: Correct, my appointment was today and the lady over there has refused to apply that for me because I am not a German citizen yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

To quote the official site:

> **Für wen wird der Personalausweis ausgestellt?**
>
> Der Personalausweis wird für deutsche Staatsangehörige ausgestellt.

Translated:

> **For whom is the identity card issued?**
>
> The identity card is issued to German citizens.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

My appointment was today and the lady over there has refused to apply that for me because I am not a German citizen yet!